# Two While Loops

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to put in one page two loops like this:

```
     // Tech Doc
   $query = "SELECT * FROM mod_doc
           WHERE doc_master_id='$master_id'";                
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $num = mysql_numrows($result);

     // Units
   $query = "SELECT * FROM mod_units
           WHERE unit_master_id='$master_id'";                
    $result2 = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $num2 = mysql_numrows($result2);
```

1st Loop

```
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

$doc_date = mysql_result($result,$i,"doc_date");
$doc_name = mysql_result($result,$i,"doc_title");
```

2nd Loop

```
 $i=0;
 while ($i < $num2) {

$unit_id = mysql_result($result,$i,"unit_id");
$unit_name = mysql_result($result,$i,"unit_name");
```

The first loop is working, the second generates this error:

```
Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: unit_name not found in MySQL result index
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You have no loops at all in your example code.

Comment: Sorry, copy/paste fails...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your second loop, use...

```
$result2
```

instead of

```
$result
```

Comment: TKS michi, worked! I had not really seen this detail... :/